# Nestjs Bull Queues creating by REST

Tags: nestjs

I create a system that will add a new repeatable action after the POST method.

In nest documentation, I saw that queues are registered in modules.

So when I'd like to add repeatable jobs, should I create one queue and using a controller just add a new job to this queue, or should I create a separated queue? If separated - how to create using a controller?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what did you mean by "should I create a separated queue?". did you meant to create a sepeate queue per repeatable job?

the answer depends on multipel factors:

1. what is the concurrency level of each and everyone of your repeatable jobs?
2. does any of them has a preiority?
3. .....
4. .....

as you can see, if all the jobs will use the same `bull-queue` options, there is no reason to create addtional queues.

---

How do you create a queue: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues

Is there something specific that is unclear in their toturial? (I used it a week ago and everything is working great in production).